# when using coda to edit css, is it possible to using firefox and see live updates?

Tags: css, coda

Is it possible for me to edit the css using coda, and view my changes live in a separate window?

I just downloaded it as I heard good things about it, and I want to learn efficient CSS coding using it.

cmd-2 and cmd-3 are shortcuts that are great, looking for any tips that would help me be fast!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be looking for a plugin called Lively

http://menumachine.com/blog/2008/12/a-live-preview-window-for-coda/

Also you can add a refresh meta tag to your HTML. This will refresh the page every 2 seconds.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2" />
```

Another solution is the XRefresh plugin for Firefox...

http://xrefresh.binaryage.com/

Hope that helps!

Comment: When writing backend code you will get errors when the page refreshes while in the middle of writing a function. XRefresh seems dead, now firebug is. Is there another alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you have the page you're building in a separate browser window and refresh with edits? Especially if you're not working off a server because you don't need to commit anything and all your files are immediately uploaded.

I know Coda has a preview screen for CSS styles. But as answered earlier you may want to try Lively if that's more what you are looking for.

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Keep an eye on on [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/). It looks as if it has an impressive feature set and will cost you a small bit.

Answer (score 0):

Lively? Coda does this already with the split window function; for example:

Split an index.html file and have one half as preview and the other in edit and you will see the preview change as you edit the editable file you have loaded.

With CSS, split the window and drag an html file from the left menu and change it to preview - saving the edited css file with update the preview.

A footnote to this is a problem where "live update" stops working - awaiting Coda's comments on this as only found one other thread online that refers to this major problem.